# Use AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack function in c#

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, tcp

How can I use that [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-allocateandgettcpextablefromstack) in c#

I need to use windows IP helper, to get specific process connections

cause it wouldn't work like this

```
        [DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack();
```

Cause I get the err:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack' in DLL 'Iphlpapi.dll'.'
```

Comment: _"wouldn't work"_ means exactly what? Please be specific, [edit] your question, and provide a [mcve] as required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-allocateandgettcpextablefromstack), this function is 'no longer available'.

The linked page suggests alternatives, you should use one of those.

> This function is no longer available for use as of Windows Vista. Instead, use the [`GetTcpTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable) or [`GetExtendedTcpTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getextendedtcptable) function to retrieve the TCP connection table.